# How to set Image As Status Bar Background

Tags: android, android-studio

I Have set an image in my ActivityMain.xml, and there is no action bar theme is used. I want
The photo that I set in the background this image will show the background of the status bar.

[image: Please Look at this image,]

Answer (score 2):

You need can achieve that by following steps:

1. Declare one theme in your `styles.xml`

> ```
> <style name="FullScreenTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
>         <item name="colorPrimary">@color/background</item>
>         <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/background</item>
>         <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
>         <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary</item>
>         <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">false</item>
>         <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation" tools:targetApi="kitkat">true</item>
>         <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@android:color/transparent</item>
> </style>
> ```

Note: `android:windowTranslucentNavigation` is important attribute here.

2. Now in your activity xml's parent layout, add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to fill your UI in full screen.
3. in your Activity class, inside `onCreate` Method, need to set `NO_LIMIT` flag like this;

> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
>     getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
>
>     setContentView(R.layout.your_xml);
>
> }
> ```

4. Now set this theme your class from android manifest.

> ```
> <activity
>     android:name=".YourActivity"
>     android:theme="@style/FullScreenTheme" />
> ```

Hope, this will helps you.

Comment: file:///F:/android%20pic/a.png my output look like this, please solve

Comment: what actually you are trying to do? first check this answer by placing your background image in your drawable folder.

Comment: Thank you, Your Idea is Good, But Not Actually I want, I have customize your idea, and it's worked. thanks. and Upvote your answer.

Comment: glad that this answer helps you somewhere.

Comment: For Android 11, the statusbar overlay is not getting set to the image. Is there any restriction with Android 11? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Abhijeet have you tried all steps?

Answer (score 0):

What I assume from your question is that you want to achieve a Full Screen Activity with your blue color as background of status bar for that you can set your status bar to transparent and your screen to stretch out to full screen

```
window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
```

Comment: Is it possible without fullScreen?

Comment: @Shagorjhin Please be more specific, it doesn't states your problem well enough. It will be helpful to figure out problem more accurately if you add image of desired output.

Comment: I want that, the background image will show in statusBar background. If I will use full screen, then status bar text not showing, so, Actually, I want, that, the background image will show in statusBar background, with statusBar text. Actually, I am not expert in english, please secrify