# How to make Status bar and App bar layout transparent?

Tags: android, transparency, android-appbarlayout, android-statusbar

I'm copying the ui of the **[Keep Notes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.keep)** app and I want to make a transparent status bar and something like a search bar that hides when scrolling through the list.

[image]

First of all, I tried to make the **Status bar** transparent in the theme resources by assigning a transparent color to it

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

But from this it only became white but not transparent. Then I used other attributes and their combinations, but nothing worked.

```
<item name="statusBarBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="statusBarForeground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

There is another attribute

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

But it makes the **Status bar** black and translucent and applying the android:statusBarColor attribute doesn't change anything

Only this line of code had any effect, the **Status bar** became transparent and now the color change attributes work

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
```

But now the **Status bar** overlaps some of the content. I tried to solve it with the following code

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(binding.appBarLayout) { v, insets ->
    v.updatePadding(top = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars()).top)
    WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED
}
```

[There was another problem, my views that are inside **AppBarLayout** are not completely hidden and are visible through the **Status bar**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxZd0.gif)

Here is the markup xml file **fragment_notes_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.notes.NotesListFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:liftOnScroll="true">

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#F2F6FB"
            app:cardCornerRadius="32dp"
            app:contentPadding="12dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:strokeWidth="0dp">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/menu"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:text="Serach your notes"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/menu"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_grid_view"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/notesList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:padding="4dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:layoutManager="StaggeredGridLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/note_item"
        tools:spanCount="2" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/newNote"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/green_300"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I also failed to make **AppBarLayout** transparent.

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Nothing changes.

I also found that in the **Keep Notes** app, the **Recyclerview** seems to have a margin top. And I thought about the opacity of **AppBarLayout**, I think it's because **AppBarLayout** is above **Recyclerview** instead of being above it, but I don't know how to do it using **CoordinatorLayout**(Is it possible achieve hiding on scroll using another **Layout**?)

[image]

**Question:** How do I fix **AppBarLayout** not being completely hidden. And how to make **AppBarLayout** transparent?

Comment: this may helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71642059/how-to-set-image-as-status-bar-background/71642556#71642556